# Disable request parameters binding when calling child action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, binding, parameters

I render a view for an action with this url: **"/search?a=1&b=2"**

The correspoding action is:

```
public ActionResult Search (int? a, int? b)
```

Inside it's view I need to call this child action:

```
public ActionResult Count (int? a, int? b)
```

But with only with "a" parameters set. So I call:

```
Html.RenderAction ("Count", new { a = 5 })
```

But my child action called as `Count (5, 2)` because there is a "b" in query string and it's been automatically binded.

Is there a way (**edit**: without need to specify "b" parameter as empty strings because I have method with a lot of parameters) to overcome this and dissalow model binder to use query string (or any other) sources of parameter values for a specific action call?

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.RenderAction("Count", new { a = 5, b = "" })
```

Comment: Correction: this is working but I'm looking into a way to tell model binder to use only those values I provide and do not use other source (form, query, ect.)

Comment: I've read something about some Attribute doing something similar. Will try to find it.

Comment: You probably mean `BindAttribute` - but it's disable automaticall parsing of the specific parameters for any action call, not just for specific one.